# Drupal7 Node table query contents

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-nodes

I migrated some 20,000 nodes from d6 to d7 and when i check on the front end some node of content is not present so i would like to know the query to check the node id whose content is null or empty...

Answer (score 0):

If by content you mean node body, then run

```
"SELECT entity_id FROM `field_data_body` WHERE body_value is Null"
```